# Как сделать такой спрайт?

Tags: photoshop, спрайт, css, вёрстка

Добрый день, подскажите как сделать такой спрайт? Нужно сделать резиновую кнопку, раньше делал кодом, и использовал pie, сейчас задача усложнилась, дизайнер нарисовал кнопку, которую уже не сделаешь кодом, из-за этого решил делать картинкой, нашел пару кнопок на сайтах, сделанных спрайтом.Как кнопку растянуть кнопку так в фотошопе? (пробовал тянуть а бордер радиус, тоже растягивается), как правильно растянуть? и как с генерировать такой спрайт? Кто пользуется спрайтами, подскажите как вы делаете?

Пример кнопки:[image]

```
<a class="blue-min-btn" href="#"><span>Купить</span></a>


.blue-min-btn {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat 100% -571px;
    height: 39px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0 7px 0 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #176097;
    text-decoration: none;
}


blue-min-btn span {
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat 0 -383px;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 5px 12px 0 19px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делишь кнопку на 3 части.

1 часть: начало + радиус(~10px)

2 часть: середина (~10-20px)

3 часть: конец + радиус (~10px)

Далее выставляешь необходимую ширину центральной части дива с повторяющейся средней картинкой background-repeat: repeat-x;

Если растянуть надо в фотошопе - то отрезаешь 3 часть и передвигаешь на сколько тебе надо пикселей. Пустое пространство копируешь и заполняешь из 2 части.